# NO me abre ANACONDA-NAVIGATOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, anaconda

Luego de realizar comandos como `conda update` entre otros y luego de actualizar y ver vídeos no consigo la solución.

Error:

```
(myEnv) C:\Users\ALEJANDRO>anaconda-navigator Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main   File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available   File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon   File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found') qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Alguien del foro que me pueda ayudar por favor.

---

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\alejandro\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ALEJAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ypg30udv\\pyside\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ALEJAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ypg30udv\\pyside\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ALEJAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ypg30udv\pyside\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\ALEJAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ypg30udv\pyside\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

---

```
(base) C:\Users\ALEJANDRO>pip install pyqt5
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in c:\users\alejandro\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (5.12)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.14 in c:\users\alejandro\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pyqt5) (4.19.19)

(base) C:\Users\ALEJANDRO>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Luego de instalar PyQt5... no se que hacer de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas instalar `pyqt5` ya que este no se instala automáticamente, usa el siguiente comando:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Comment: me da error nuevamente

Comment: Intenta instalando `PySide`, `pip install PySide`

Comment: ahora me dio otro error lo colacolare abajo